# installing yfinance python package in docker container

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, archlinux, yfinance

I am trying to modify this [docker compose](https://github.com/datascienceie/datascience-tools-compose) setup to install a number of python packages including [yfinance](https://github.com/ranaroussi/yfinance). In my mind there are three ways to install packages and i'd like to be able to use each one in docker:

- install from pip requirements file
- install from conda environments.yml file
- install manually in environment by running install command (`pip install yfinance` or `conda install -c conda-forge beautifulsoup4`)

Here is a list of the problems I am having trying to modify this setup:

- pip requirements file. - After altering this file the packages don't appear to be installed and instead the file is overridden with [defaults on github](https://github.com/datascienceie/datascience-tools-compose/blob/master/services/jupyter/Dockerfile).
- conda environment file - Unable to create environment and install packages from [environment.yml](https://medium.com/@chadlagore/conda-environments-with-docker-82cdc9d25754)
- manual install of package - entering a docker container shell using `docker exec -it <containername> /bin/bash` results in pip and conda returning command not found in bash.

Results so far:

- All of the above methods have resulted in errors including 'command not found' or 'no module named yfinance' when importing in a notebook.
- The only way I've been able to have any success so far is opening a notebook in the browser at localhost:8888 and creating a new notebook and running `!pip install yfinance`. However importing and executing the following code also results in an error making me think the package or dependencies haven't installed correctly.

  import yfinance as yf
  m = yf.Ticker("MSFT")
  m.info

Here is my docker-compose file service

```
   jupyter:
        image: cmihai/jupyter:v1
        container_name: 'joshnotebook'
        hostname: jupyter
        restart: 'always'
        ports:
          - '8888:8888'
        env_file:
          - notebook/config/jupyter.env
        volumes:
          - ${USERDIR}/docker/notebook:/home/user/notebook
        build: ./notebook/services/jupyter
```

Here is my Dockerfile

```
FROM cmihai/python:v1
LABEL name="cmihai/jupyterlab" \
      version="1" \
      maintainer="Mihai Criveti <crivetimihai@gmail.com>" \
      description="Anaconda Python with Jupyter Lab\
      This container installs Anaconda Python 3 and Jupyter Lab."
SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-l", "-c"]
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive

# PARAMETERS
ARG OS_PACKAGES="tzdata curl graphviz vim-nox gosu mc sqlite3 bash-completion sudo"
#ARG LATEX_PACKAGES="texlive texlive-latex-base texlive-latex-extra texlive-xetex texlive-generic-recommended texlive-fonts-extra texlive-fonts-recommended pandoc"
ARG CONDA_PACKAGES="jupyterlab pandas"
COPY condaenvironment.yml /tmp/condaenvironment.yml

# ROOT
USER root

# INSTALL OS PACKAGES
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get --no-install-recommends install --yes ${OS_PACKAGES} \ # ${LATEX_PACKAGES}\
    && apt-get clean \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN conda install -c ranaroussi yfinance

# SWITCH TO REGULAR USER
RUN mkdir /home/user/notebook && chown -R user:user /home/user/notebook \
    && echo 'user    ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL' >> /etc/sudoers
USER user

# INSTALL CONDA PACKAGES
RUN . ~/.profile \
    && unset SUDO_UID SUDO_GID SUDO_USER \
    && conda install --quiet --yes ${CONDA_PACKAGES} \
    && conda install -c anaconda requests \
    && conda install -c conda-forge lxml \
    && conda install -c conda-forge beautifulsoup4 \
    && conda install -c conda-forge sqlalchemy \
    && conda install -c anaconda mysql-connector-python \
    && conda install -c conda-forge seaborn \
    && conda install -c conda-forge altair \
    && conda clean -y -all

# INSTALL PIP PACKAGES
RUN . ~/.profile \
    && python -m pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade pip \
    && python -m pip install yfinance

# WORKDIR
WORKDIR /home/user

# JUPYTERLAB EXTENSIONS
RUN jupyter labextension install jupyterlab-drawio \
    && jupyter labextension install jupyterlab_bokeh \
    && jupyter labextension install plotlywidget \
    && jupyter labextension install @jupyterlab/plotly-extension \
    && jupyter labextension install jupyterlab-chart-editor \
    && jupyter labextension install @jupyterlab/git \
    && jupyter serverextension enable --py jupyterlab_git \
    && jupyter labextension install @jupyterlab/latex \
    && jupyter labextension install @jupyterlab/toc \
    && jupyter labextension install @oriolmirosa/jupyterlab_materialdarker \
    && jupyter labextension install @jupyterlab/geojson-extension \
    && jupyter lab build

# COMMAND and ENTRYPOINT:
COPY start-jupyter.sh /home/user/start-jupyter.sh
CMD ["/home/user/start-jupyter.sh"]
```